# No "Apache Tomcat 7.0" entry in Eclipse Europa

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I have a simple problem in Eclipse Europa. I'm trying to create a Tomcat 7 server, but in **Window > Preferences > Server > Installed Runtime** I only have entries for Tomcat 3.2 to 6.0. I want to add Tomcat 7.0. How can I add this entry?

The **Download extra server adapters** option only suggests Geronimo adapters, but no Tomcat 7.0.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Europa was long time ago. Maybe Tomcat 7.0 was not supported at this time?

Comment: Was it? Then why the hell did the Eclipse website send it to me?
I'm gonna try Kepler and come back to you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It was a first official version by eclipse launched in 2007, obviously at that time tomcat 7 was not launched and eclipse has stopped to give update, try **juno** or **kepler**, **kepler** is still new and under developer reviews, I would recommend you to go for **juno**.